# C# count emojis as two characters

Tags: c#, regex, twitter, emoji

The Twitter API gives back a list of entities with start/end indices indicated where the entity starts and ends in the tweet text.

When the tweet text includes emojis these indices are off by 1 for each emoji in the text. Every emoji in the tweet text consists of two unicode characters (`\ud83d\udc4c`). My assumption is that in C# these are counted as two characters instead of one, which makes all indices be off (and increasingly off depending on the number of emojis).

So I looked into [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) which is Twitter's official emoji library. This is using a regular expression ([see twemoji JS code](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/blob/gh-pages/twemoji.js#L236)) to find emojis in the text. I copied this regex into my code to replace emojis with a single character (to be replaced at a later point by an image, but for now an `X` will suffice). I copy the pattern, escape all backslashes, remove `/` from the start and `/g` from the end. C# then gladly accepts the regex and I can use this code to replace all emojis with `X`:

```
string strippedText = Regex.Replace(text, emojiRegex, "X");
```

However, some tweets seem to include emojis not (yet?) supported by twemoji, like i.e. `\ud83c\udffb`, which cause my stripping to not strip everything and indices to be off again.

How can I find any non-supported emojis and strip those away as well? Is there a generic regex I can use for this, or are there any other (and better) regex' out there that catches more emojis?

Or even better, is there a way to have C# understand that a string containing emojis only count them as one character and not as two?

Comment: If you just want to count grapheme clusters, maybe `StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator` is what you're looking for, or just `new StringInfo("\ud83c\udffb").LengthInTextElements`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the tip. I ended up using `int[] textIndices = StringInfo.ParseCombiningCharacters(tweet.Text);` from the same class instead as a lookup of entity index to actual index, and now everything works as I want it to! :) Feel free to add this info as an answer and I'll award you the answer.

Comment: @GTHvidsten would you have time to discuss your solution with me on gitter.im/linvi? I am the developer of Tweetinvi a library to access the Twitter API and I stumbled on this problematic too.

I ended up with the following code : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/2.1/Tweetinvi.Core/Core/Helpers/UnicodeHelper.cs

But I would like to share your opinion on the subject.

Cheers